# Syntax error on javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting syntax error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

My code

```
 <button onclick="alert('document.getElementById('todo.age').value');">onclick</button>
```

Comment: You can't have a dot in the name of an argument. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Do you really have an input with `id="todo.age"`? It's not a good idea to put dots in IDs, because CSS uses dots as class prefixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in controller add

```
$scope.alert = function(age) {
    alert(age);
}
```

in html change like this:

```
<button ng-click="alert(todo.age);">onclick</button>
```

Comment: its working but i want to return the value from the json ..but it's not getting

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/JodNsW/preview try this i want to get element id from the json value

Comment: see my new update, this work.   http://plnkr.co/edit/p45VPnqUPzS3MqdbshBw?p=preview

Comment: @gjramanaa. In your fiddle I can't see any `input` with that `id`. Which's element's value are you trying to display?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('todo.age').value);">onclick</button>
```

You shouldn't quote the argument to `alert` if you want to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

if u need value of the todo.age id values use the following code.    `<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('todo.age').value);">onclick</button>`

or else of u want to print the whole text `document.getElementById('todo.age').value` like this
use 
`<button onclick="alert('document.getElementById('todo.age').value');">onclick</button>` code/

Answer (score 0):

It will start working better if you separate your HTML code and JavaScript.
Kind of this.
HTML:

```
<button id="button">onclick</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  button.onclick = function()
  {
    //do some action here
  }
}
```

This will help you to avoid simple syntax errors.